# Store function pointer and call it with safe type checking in c++

Tags: c++, events, c++17, function-pointers, variant

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this issue most elegantly using c++17 (without boost!). I'm working on a library providing UI controls. Controls should be able to react to events and user (using the library) should be able to add his handlers for these events. I want to avoid the [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) since this is too complicated for the user - he just wants to define one function and assign it to some Event and UI control. Here's some sample code:

```
// My library
class Base; // Base class for all the UI controls

class ListBox : public Base {
    // handlers reacting on clicking the item in listbox
    std::vector<std::variant<std::function<void()>, 
                             std::function<void(int)>>> click_handlers_;
    // handlers reacting on changing the name of the item in listbox
    std::vector<std::variant<std::function<void()>,
                             std::function<void(std::string, std::string)>>> edit_handlers_;
public:
    void AddHandler(Event ev, const std::function< ? ? ? > handler);
};

// USER's code
int main() {
    ListBox lb;
    lb.AddHandler(Event::Click, [](int index) { DoSomethingWithItem(i); });
    lb.AddHandler(Event::Edit, [](std::string old_name, std::string new_name)
                                     { DoSomethingWithItemNames(old_name, new_name); });
    lb.AddHandler(Event::Edit, []() { DoSomeCleanup(); });
}
```

When `Event::Edit` (of type `enum`) event happens, it triggers `DoSomethingWithItemNames()` which needs both of the arguments. Right after that, the `DoSomeCleanup()` does its job and the event is handled (at least from the user's point of view).

1. Problem: For every LisBox Event I have to define a separate handler vector.
2. Problem: What should be the type of the second argument of `ListBox::AddHandler` method?

Is there any way to unify these handlers, so that the user can use only one function `AddHandler()` and not separate functions like `AddClickHandler()` and `AddEditHandler()`? Of course, the function types should be checked statically and any type mismatches should be reported to the user in compile-time. Is there a standard way to treat this whole concept? Bear in mind, that every control has its events and my idea is, that every event can be assigned a handler function with no arguments. Thanks.

**EDIT**

After consideration, another problem popped up. the design of the library looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60752964/how-to-avoid-downcasting-in-this-specific-class-hierarchy-design). The events are generated by the system which then calls pre-defined framework methods, from which I need to call user's handlers (e.g. in Qt, the signal `itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)` is emitted when the item is double-clicked inside the QListWidget). Therefore, an implementation class (`FrameWorkAListBox`) needs access to the stored handlers (which are currently in a wrapper class `ListBox`). There are more frameworks intended to be used, so where and how should I store them, so that they are not duplicate and the architecture stays easily extensible?

**EDIT 2**

After a few tries and more studying, I ended up with this solution:

```
// first define some aliases
template<class... Args>
using Handler = std::function<void(Args...)>; // event handler

template<class... Args>
using VariableHandler = std::variant<Args...>;

template<class T>
using Event = std::list<T>; // list of handler variants

// this is for easier std::visit use, taken from
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...)->overloaded<Ts...>;

// ListBox.cpp - interface class, used by the user
void ListBox::AddDoubleClickHandler(
            const VariableHandler<Handler<>, Handler<int>>& handler) {
    // forwards the handler to the implementation class (pushes the 
    // handler into the ev_double_click_ vector since wrapper class cannot
    // have any other private fields aside from pointer to the 
    // implementation (according to pimpl idiom)
}

// ListBoxWindowsImpl.h - native Windows class representing UI control
class ListBoxImpl : public SomeNativeWindowsListBoxClass {
public:
    // double-click event handler can have 0 or 1int argument
    Event<VariableHandler<Handler<>, Handler<int>>> ev_double_click_;
    // this gets called automatically by the system, when the user
    // double-clicks an item within the listbox
    void OnItemDoubleClick(int index) {
        for (const auto& h : ev_double_click_) {
            std::visit(overloaded {
                [](Handler<> arg) { arg(); },
                [index](Handler<int> arg) { arg(index); },
            }, h);
        }
    }
```

I would like to know if there's a way to add new handlers without the need of adding a new function to the ListBox class. It would be nice if adding the double-click handler and new handlers (e.g. selection change, single-click...) could be done by a single function, something like ListBox::AddHandler. And the best would be if the body of this method wouldn't need to be changed when adding a new handler so that the interface of the library (in this case ListBox class) wouldn't need to be recompiled. Thanks.

Comment: You could provide two or more `AddHandler`s - for each flavor of function one. However, to prevent that `Event::Click` is combined with `std::function<void(std::string, std::string)>`, you need a different approach - two `enum`s (each with only one value). (I saw this trick once in gtkmm to distinguish constructors with otherwise identical parameters.) You may decide on your own what you like more: `AddClickHandler(f)` vs. `AddHandler(ClickEvent, f)`. IMHO, it's a question of personal taste...

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope this helps and best of luck. :)

Comment: Hello. I have updated my answer once again.
The third time's the charm as they say. Hope this time, I could solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could either make separate overload for each possibility, make two overloads with the two variants or define it just once with an argument of type `std::variant` that can take all three possible `std::function`s.
As far as I know those are our current options that do not involve creating a wrapper classes that derive from one base, which would, again, make it act like a `std::variant`.

### Answer on edit

As far as I understand your question, you want to expose the user handlers to the framework beneath your wrapping/abstraction layer class. If that is the case, then there are three solutions that come to mind that won't lead to having data duplicated (in this case handler pointers):

1. Exposing the handlers from the wrapping class by giving the framework a way to access them (e.g. a pointer to function that returns a list/array of the handlers), if this is allowed by the framework (which is a rare thing)
2. Passing the "add handler" requests directly to be handled by the framework and then accessing them by a (let's call it) "handle" (e.g. function, public member, etc.) provided by the framework (which is in my opinion should be common enough as an option)
3. Keep the handlers in global-scope lists/arrays (which is usually not a good practice and is probably not an option for the framework)

Hope this helps. If not, then the only other thing is to store the handlers in the wrapper class AND pass them to the framework for it to be able to use them too. Which in turn lead to data duplication, but is the only other option that comes to my mind, if the above ones aren't possible.

### Answer on second edit

Please note, that this is proof-of-concept and *could* use some refinement.

Note that you won't be changing the signature **but** the function body itself and the member data (the patterns).

I have added additional `size_t` for each pattern, but if not needed you can replace the `map<size_t, vector<const char*>>` with just `vector<const char*>` or any other container.

You can also replace the `const char*` with `string` for example too.

Just keep in mind that it needs to be able to store the `typeid(...).name()`.

Keep in mind, that when patterns are defined, they expect the **same** type, a.k.a. function argument types are **not** checked whether they can be implicitly cast to the defined argument type.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct TypeCheckHelper {
private:
    template<class T>
    static bool _type_check_helper(vector<const char*>::const_iterator type)
    {
        return typeid(T).name() == string(*type);
    }

    template<class T1, class T2, class... Args>
    static bool _type_check_helper(vector<const char*>::const_iterator type)
    {
        if (typeid(T1).name() != string(*type)) return false;
        return TypeCheckHelper::_type_check_helper<T2, Args...>(++type);
    }

public:
    template<class... Args>
    static bool type_check_helper(const vector<const char*>& types)
    {
        if (types.size() != sizeof...(Args)) {
            return false;
        }
        return TypeCheckHelper::_type_check_helper<Args...>(types.cbegin());
    }

    template<class... Args>
    static bool type_check_helper(vector<const char*>&& types)
    {
        if (types.size() != sizeof...(Args)) {
            return false;
        }
        return TypeCheckHelper::_type_check_helper<Args...>(types.cbegin());
    }
};

template<>
bool TypeCheckHelper::type_check_helper<>(vector<const char*>&& types)
{
    return !types.size();
}

class InternalListClass { /* ... */ }; // e.g.: Windows' List implementation

class ExposedListClass {
public:
    // ...

    enum EventType_e {
        CLICK,
        DOUBLE_CLICK,
        // ...
    };

    template<class... Args>
    bool AddHandler(EventType_e event_type, function<void(Args...)> callback) {
        for (const pair<size_t, vector<const char*>>& pattern : patterns[event_type]) /* For each pattern for this event type */
        {
            if (TypeCheckHelper::type_check_helper<Args...>(pattern.second)) /* Does it have the SAME (no implicit casting included) parameters */ {
                /* Pattern matched */

                switch (event_type) {
                case CLICK:
                    // Register callback
                    /* OR */
                    switch (pattern.first) /* Pattern's ID */
                    {
                    case 0:
                        // Register callback as one type
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // Register callback as another type
                        break;
                    // ...
                    default: /* Unknown pattern ID */
                        return false; /* OR throw */
                    }
                    break;
                case DOUBLE_CLICK:
                    // ...
                    break;
                // case ...:
                    // Register callback
                default: /* Unknown event type */
                    return false; /* OR throw */
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false; /* Didn't match any of the patterns */
        /* Possible to "throw" to indicate error too */
    }

    // ...

private:
    static const map<EventType_e, map<size_t, vector<const char*>>> patterns;

    // ...
};

/* Can not be statically initialized within the class */
const map<ExposedListClass::EventType_e, map<size_t, vector<const char*>>> ExposedListClass::patterns {
    {
        /* Event type */
        CLICK,
        {
            /* Patterns */
            {
                0, /* Pattern ID */
                /* Variant 1 */
                {
                    /* No parameters */
                },
            },
            {
                1, /* Pattern ID */
                /* Variant 2 */
                {
                    typeid(int).name(), /* First Parameter */
                },
            },
            {
                2, /* Pattern ID */
                /* Variant 3 */
                {
                    typeid(int).name(), /* First Parameter */
                    typeid(double).name(), /* Second Parameter */
                },
            },
        }
    },
    {
        /* Event type */
        DOUBLE_CLICK,
        {
            /* Patterns */
            {
                0, /* Pattern ID */
                /* Only one variant */
                {
                    typeid(int).name(), /* First Parameter */
                }
            }
        }
    },
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will probably go for the single definition, but first I need to solve another issue, which I added to my question, could you please check that out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Following up on your edit: 1st option is not possible since the I will probably implement the relationship between the wrapper and it's implementation as a pimpl idiom - then the wrapper class cannot have any private fields except pimpl (pointer to implementation). The 3rd option, as you already mentioned, is not a good practice, so I will probably go for the 2nd one. I will accept your answer as soon as it's done, thanks very much!

Comment: I implemented the solution which is similar to your 2nd point. I edited the question, could you please check that out and give me some insight? Thanks a lot.